# How tp parse Json result which is returned with an arraylist in a webmethod?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

This is a simplified code. I have a `webservice` `(.asmx)` as following:
I store some values in `Test class` and then store the `class` in an `arraylist`.
I do this two times in two different `arraylists`.
and then store these two array lists in a `third arraylist.`
and then pass this `arraylist` as `output of webmethod.`

```
 private class Test
        {
            public string Id;
            public string Name;
        }
```

[webmethod]

```
      public ArrayList RuleReport(long RuleId)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.Id = "1";
        t.Name = "a";

        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList ar2 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList ar3 = new ArrayList();

        ar.Add(t);

t = new Test();
        t.Id = "2";
        t.Name = "b";
        ar2.Add(t);
        ar3.Add(ar);
        ar3.Add(ar2);
        return ar3;
    }
```

and in `js` file I want to parse he `json` result to read each `Id` and `Name` values of two `arraylists`.

```
id=1,name=a
id=2,name=b
```

this is my jquery code:

```
 $.ajax(
{ url: " Ajaxes/Rules.asmx/RuleReport",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'RuleId':'79'}",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.d, function(index, obj) {
    alert(obj.d[0].Id);// something like this. How to do it???
        })

    }, error: function() { }
});
```

this is the json response in fire bug:

```
{"d":[[{"Id":"1","Name":"a"}],[{"Id":"2","Name":"b"}]]}
```

how to get every `Id` and `Name` values???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current setup inside `$.each` loop you are getting

```
[{"Id":"1","Name":"a"}]
```

as `obj`. As you can see it's a `array of object` with only `one object` as it's content. You can access that `object` with `obj[0]` and then their properties can be accessed with `obj[0].Id` and `obj[0].Name`

You can do this with the following code

```
$.each(data.d,function(index,obj){

       var id = obj[0].Id;
       var name = obj[0].Name;
       // do what ever you want with them
   })​
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/uhxBT/)